# how to access a class attribute from within the class in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following SQLAlchemy code

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'currency'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    symbol = Column(String(4), nullable=False, unique=True)

    l =  session.query(Foo.symbol, Foo.id).all()
```

In the last line, I am trying to generate a list of the symbol-id pairs. It produces the following error:

> NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined

I tried the following and got the errors as specified:

```
l = session.query(models.Foo.symbol, models.Foo.id).all()
#note: The Foo object is in the models.py file
#error: NameError: name 'models' is not defined

l = session.query(symbol, id).all()
#error: sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Cannot compile Column object until its 'name' is assigned.

l = session.query(self.symbol, self.id).all()
#error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So how do I pass in Foo object's column names to the SqlAlhemy query from inside the Foo class?

Why am I doing this? I am then converting the list to a dictionary and only access the dictionary from code throughout the program since its values are seldom changed. So I want to populate it once and then access it many many times without hitting the DB again. And I want to keep it in the Foo Class which I believe is where it belongs.

If there is a better way to do this please do let me know.

Comment: Don't do this, because it will cause a query at *import* time.

Comment: Btw those aren't just normal class attributes, they're descriptors for the ORM.

Comment: @wim I think that would be fine. Because I am then converting the list to a dictionary and only access the dictionary from code throughout the program since its values are seldom changed.  So I want to populate it once and then access it many many times without hitting the DB again.

Comment: @wim so how do I access these descriptors from within the class? I am trying to encapsulate all the Foo stuff inside Foo and not have them spread all over the place.

Comment: Well you can't do it like this, because the class doesn't exist yet.  Suppose you add another row to the currency table, how do you want `Foo.l` to be updated? Magic?

Comment: Easy peasy. There would be a method called getIdForSymbol. It takes the symbol as imput and returns the id by first looking it up in the dictionary. If it doesn't find it in the dictionary then it calls the same query to update the dictionary from the database. 99.9999 percent of the time, this method does not have to hit the database because Foo data is not updated much but read a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165686/discussion-between-barka-and-wim).

Comment: So you want to store the id/symbol mapping entirely in memory, and you want the cache populated at import time.  When you delete a row in the database, how is your run-time cache going to be invalidated?

Comment: Nothing gets deleted from this table. If it is, the symbol will not be submitted to  getIdForSymbol for the lookup. And if it is deleted and a symbol comes in then it is time to re-insert the symbol. Also, the Id is a DB generated int primary key, so once a record is deleted from the database, the id will never be re-used. Also, this table is referenced as a foreign key by many other tables. you just can't accidentally delete a record from this since the database is set up to disallow cascading of deletes.

Comment: I have used this pattern with great success in other languages. I am however new to Python and don't quite understand how to achieve it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the class before it has been defined.  And you can't use `symbol` and `id` yet, *even though the names can be correctly resolved from within the class block itself*, because the ORM hasn't had a chance to prepare the columns yet.  This is one of tasks of declarative `Base`, and `Foo` will inherit a metaclass which needs to prepare the model.

Assuming you set up the session correctly, you should be able to dynamically contribute this attribute on the class *outside* of the class definition block:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'currency'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    symbol = Column(String(4), nullable=False, unique=True)

Foo.l =  session.query(Foo.symbol, Foo.id).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for trying to make sure I was not shooting myself in the foot by this design. This pattern is only useful for very specific data and as you suggested, should generally be avoided. I have implemented as you suggest. Will leave the question open for a few days just to see if others might contribute alternatives.